# Is it possible to reference an input outpoint more than once in a transaction?

Tags: transaction-input, sighash-flags, sighash

For example, could you have the following transaction:

A --> B 
A --> C

Where A is an input txid and index, and B and C are outputs? The reason I'm asking is because I believe with SIGHASH_SINGLE you can only sign one input and one output, so this would be a way to use the same input to spend to two outputs. It would be the equivalent of sighash 'double', if it existed.

For example, to have a transaction like this:

A --> B
A --> C
D --> E

Where the D --> E input and output could be added after the first two inputs had been signed. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible - once an outpoint is consumed by a transaction, it is considered spent, including within the same transaction.

Your only option here would be to have an intermediary transaction splitting A (or using another input), and then using the two outputs from that as inputs along with `SIGHASH_SINGLE | SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY` for your flags.

```
A -> A1
 \-> A2

A1 -> B
A2 -> C
D  -> E
```

Note that SIGHASH_SINGLE signs a single *output* and all of the inputs. If you want someone else to be able to add inputs, you need the `ANYONECANPAY` flag as well